# Marketing Cloud SQL Birthday date (smalldatetime) is equal to today

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql

i am trying to filter with a SQL query a data extension. I tried to get the people in de DE which have their birthday today. The format of the birthday field is i think smalldatetime. This is how it looks like "4/6/1980 12:00:00 AM".

If i try something like:

```
select convert(date, contact.Birthdate) as Birthday
from Contact_Salesforce contact
where contact.Birthdate = GetDate()
```

It provides 0 results because the contact.Birthdate outputs smalldatetime as a value like this: "4/6/1980 12:00:00 AM". Can someone help me with this?

Comment: where is your FROM clause?

Comment: Oops.. forgot to put that in the question. Question updated now.

Comment: can you explain "won't work" - does it error, provide 0 results, provide incorrect results, etc?

Comment: It provides 0 results because the contact.Birthdate outputs smalldatetime as a value like this: "4/6/1980 12:00:00 AM".

Comment: I don't believe you would want to include the year in your comparison either, unless you are expecting people that were literally born today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make a comparison on equally formatted values, try something like this:

```
select convert(date, contact.Birthdate) as Birthday
from Contact_Salesforce contact
where CONVERT(date, contact.Birthdate) = CONVERT(date, GetDate())
```

This should match them on the MM/dd/yyyy format (e.g. 04/24/2018) instead of potentially comparing apples to oranges due to format differences.

---

**EDIT** - As @AnonWonderer stated, I believe it is the year that is throwing it off.

Try below instead:

```
select convert(date, contact.Birthdate) as Birthday
from Contact_Salesforce contact
where DATEPART("month", contact.Birthdate) = DATEPART("month", GetDate())
AND DATEPART("day", contact.Birthdate) = DATEPART("day", GetDate())
```

Comment: Thanks for you help Gortonington. I get the following error using your code: An error occurred while checking the query syntax. Errors: 'FORMAT' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: I apologize, I updated the answer and it should now fit in SFMC restrictions.

Comment: It still returns 0 results.

Comment: Your updated answer did the job Gortonington! Thanks for your help!